# How to get an instances of saved realm objects in my SwiftUI DeviceActivityMonitorExtension point in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have initialized realm in the init of the @main app point like this:

```
init() {
        
    let fileURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.identifier")!                     
            .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
        
    let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)
        
        // Set this configuration as the default for Realm across the app
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

And i have a realm data manager like this:

```
class SetupDataManager {
    static let shared = SetupDataManager()
    
    private var realm: Realm {
        get {
            return try! Realm() 
        }
    }
    
    private init() {}

    func fetchBalancedActivityModel(by id: String) async -> BalancedActivityModel? {
        return realm.object(ofType: BalancedActivityModel.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
    }
}
```

And these work well enough for when the app is active and i want to save and fetch the balancedActivityModels and even use `@ObservedResults(BalancedActivityModel.self) var balancedActionItems` in my views.

However i'm also using the DeviceActivity api and i want to fetch these balancedActivityModels in my `DeviceActivityMonitorExtension` and specifically when the function `eventDidReachThreshold` gets called.

Now i'm confused about how to initialize another realm and thread to go with it and access the saved models in the background.. currently i have the function implemented like this but this really doesn't work

```
    override func eventDidReachThreshold(_ event: DeviceActivityEvent.Name, activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.eventDidReachThreshold(event, activity: activity)
        let fileURL = FileManager.default
            .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.identifier")!
            .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
        let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
        
        let realm = try! Realm()
        
        guard let balancedActivityModel = realm.object(ofType: BalancedActivityModel.self, forPrimaryKey: activity.rawValue) else {
            return
        }
        
        .. rest of the code like
        realm.writeAsync {
            balancedActivityModel.timeIsUp = true
            balancedActivityModel.count += 1
        }
        
        doesn't work..
    }
```

Any tips appreciated!

Initialize new realm from extension..

Comment: *this really doesn't work* - is vague. What about it doesn't work. Is it crashing? Provide erroneous data? Can you clarify what the issue is and include your troubleshooting and which like of code is not working as expected? You can do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected.

Comment: Not working as in it completely ignores the realm code and whatever is after it, it's hard to debug since familyActivityPicker only works on physical device and i can't debug it well with breakpoints etc because of that.. Do you have tips on how to access realm saved models in extensions? Is my implementation even a bit in the right direction?

Comment: If the code is not running at all, that would indicate the function is not being called. That then leads to the issue being with the code that's supposed to call that function - which is code that has nothing to do with Realm. e.g. if you remove the Realm code completely, the function is still not called - so that's where to start troubleshooting, which the calling or initialization code.